# Unplayed games appear in Steam jumplist after reboot

Tags: steam

A few days ago I set up family sharing with my brother.  Since then, whenever I restart steam, Dota 2 and Dota 2 - English Depot appear at the top of my steam jumplist (both from steam taskbar and tooltray icon).  I have neither game installed and have never played them.  Since I do most of my game launching from the tooltray icon, this is quite inconvenient for me.  The three games shown below these stay up to date as my last 3 played games.

More specifically let's say my jumplist is

- Dota 2 - English Depot
- Dota 2
- Game 1
- Game 2
- Game 3

I then Launch games 4-8 so that my jump list looks like

- Game 4
- Game 5
- Game 6
- Game 7
- Game 8

Then I restart steam.  After the restart my jumplist will be

- Dota 2 - English Depot
- Dota 2
- Game 4
- Game 5
- Game 6

I have tried a couple things to resolve this.  Removing the games from the jumplist manually (right click on taskbar steam, remove from list) works for the taskbar icon, but does not affect the tooltray icon's list and does not persist through steam restart.  I also tried hiding all Dota 2 games in my library but that had no effect on the jumplist.

Prior to adding family sharing, I had not added Dota 2 to my library.  Since my brother had, the game was automatically added when we shared.  It was the only game my brother had that was free-to-play that I did not already have installed, so I am wondering if that has anything to do with it.

I am looking for some way to correct the behavior of my jumplist, specifically the one from the tooltray icon.

Comment: Do you only own 3 games? I'm not sure exactly how jumplist works and if it always shows a certain amount of games (mine shows 5 most recent).

Comment: I own over 200, and up until this weekend it always showed my 5 most recently played.  Now it shows the two Dota 2 games and my 3 most recently played.

Comment: This is a bug with Steam that happens for me too. I am unaware of a fix or workaround besides just launching a bunch of games to push them off the list whenever it happens.

Comment: @Keavon Is it Dota 2 for you as well, or other games?

Comment: @GodricSeer I don't have that game in my library. It's just random games from the best I can tell and its choices change around over time. It's a good way for me to see some of the games in my library that I've never heard!

Comment: If it was random, i would be much more accepting of it.  I am going to try installing steam on a different computer, and then if I can't resolve it I will look into reporting a bug to valve

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the issue, nor can I find any solutions, mostly because no one on the internet can tell the difference between taskbar jumplist and system tray jumplist, making searching for solutions a major pain. I'm removing my answer, since it's not helping.

Comment: I have the same thing. With my steam it's always Audiosurf which I have never even installed let alone played.